# Java JAXB Marshalling the elements to the objects in inner class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I trying to use the `JAXB` annotation to convert the JSON  data to XML. I have the `JSON` somewhat like this:

```
{
   "Employee": {
      "name": "Tanmay",
      "Email": "tanmaypatil@xyz.com",
      "Address": {
         "City": "Florida",
         "State": "Miami"
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to use marshalling to create the XML which would look something like this:
(Please note the `extension` tag which is not present in `JSON` but I need to add in `XML`)

```
<Company>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>
        <extension>
            <Address>
                <City>Florida</City>
                <State>Miami</State>
            </Address>
        </extension>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

I have the following classes:

My main class would actually read the JSON data and marshal it to XML. I have used Jackson to read the JSON data for simplicity purpose I have removed that code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(new File(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("InputEPCISEvents.json").toURI()));
        //I am using the JAKSON jsonParser to read the JSON file and automatically map it to the child classes 
        //Ommiting the JACKSON JsonParser code for simplicity purpose
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
        Marshaller mar = context.createMarshaller();
        mar.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        mar.marshal(eventInfo, System.out);
        System.out.println("-----------------");
    }
}
```

Following is my Parent class which would be mapped to Incoming JSON:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlTransient
public class Employee{
    
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Address address;
    
    //getters and setters are ommited
    //Noargs and allargs constuctor ommited
    
}
```

Following is my `Address` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Extension", propOrder = { "name","email","city","state"})
private class Address extends Employee{
    
    @XmlElement(name = "extension")
    private Extension extension;
    
    public Extension getExtension() {
        extension.setCity(getCity());
        extension.setState(getState());
        return extension;
    }
    
    public Extension setExtension(Extension extension) {
        this.setCity(extension.getCity());
        this.setState(extension.getState());
        this.extension = extension;
    }
}
```

Following is the `Extension` class that I have created as `Extension` tag will not be present within the incoming JSON but I need to add it to the `XML` during the marshaling:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Extension{
    private String city;
    private String state;
    
    //getters and setters are ommited
    //Noargs and allargs constuctor ommited
}
```

I would like to know how to do the following things using the `JAXB`. I am fine with creating some additional classes or modifying the existing class but I cannot change the incoming `JSON` or `XML` that I am creating as they are standard format.

1. How can I map the `address`,`city`,`state` from JSON to Class object. If the elements are present within the `Address.class` then it can be mapped automatically but since I want the `extension` tag in `XML` I have moved them to my `Extension.class` hence the `JAXB` cannot recognize it and its not mapping to objects.
2. How to add the additional `extension` tag to the `XML` that will be created during the marshalling. As we can see the `JSON` does not contain the `extension` tag but I need it in the `XML`. If its collection then I can use the `@XmlElementWrapper` but in my case it's not Collection.

I tried searching a lot but could not find anything that helps me. So based on my understanding I have done above mentioned things. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to do this using the `Moxy @XmlPath`. If you are using the `Moxy` then you can use the `@XmlPath` and add the additional tags and do not have to create any additional classes.

For example here in this case I do not have to create `Extension.class` but stil I can add the `extension` tag to my XML. Moxy is and implementation based on JAXB.

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out a lot of things. Hence, posting the same as it can be helpful to someone in the future.

1. You can find how to configure `Moxy` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67515165/7584240). Do not worry its very simple.
2. You can find how to use `@XmlPath` [from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67615850/7584240)

There you go with few very simple steps you can get the wrapper tags in your XML for even non-collection items. Also, no need to create multiple additional classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to register **all** used classes in your JAXBContext

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class, Extension.class, ...)
```

Alternatively, you can also pass the "root" package of all your classes:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.demo.beans")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I tried this actually but that did not work. I tried the first method by passing the class name that did not make any difference. I cannot pass the package name because the `Extension.class` is present within some other Maven project.