# How to add wrapper element to class during the JAXB marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

I am trying to create `XML` using the `Moxy Marshalling` approach. Everything seems to be working fine except for one small thing. Basically, I would like to know how to add wrapper element to the class itself during the marshalling.

As we are aware we can add `@XmlPath("test/name/text()")` to add a wrapper to any of the `String` elements. Also for collection we can make use of `@XmlElementWrapper(name="languages")`, `@XmlElement(name="language")`. But these are for the fields within the `class`. How can I add the wrapper element to the class itself which is being marshalled?

I have the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
@XmlType(name="customer",propOrder={"name","languages"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)   
public class Customer{
    
    @XmlPath("extension/name/text()")
    private String name;
    
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "languages")
    @XmlElement(name = "language")
    private List<String> languages;
    
    //Getter, Setter and other constuctors
}
```

This will produce the output `XML` something like this:

```
<customer>
    <extension>
        <name>Hello</name>
    </extension>
    <languages>
        <language>English</language>
        <language>UK English</language>
    </languages>
</customer>
```

However, I would like to add the `wrapper` element to event the whole class so that output would look something like this: (Notice the whole `customer` is wrapper within `classWrapper`)

```
<classWrapper>
    <customer>
        <extension>
            <name>Hello</name>
        </extension>
        <languages>
            <language>English</language>
            <language>UK English</language>
        </languages>
    </customer>
</classWrapper>
```

I tried adding the `@XmlPath` and `@XmlElementWrapper` to the `Customer` class but it throws an error as it can be added only to the fields within the class but not to the whole class.

Following is my `Main` class which would be used for marshalling:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        
        List<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();
        languages.add("English");
        languages.add("UK English");
        
        customer.setName("Hello");
        customer.setLanguages(languages);
        
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(customer,System.out);
     }
}
```

I am aware that I can write another `wrapper` class add the custom field to it then use that `wrapper` class for the `marshalling`. Actually, I am doing the same as of now. However, trying to find if there is some `Moxy` approach of doing this similar to how we have `@XmlPath` and `@XmlElementWrapper`

Can someone please suggest some form of `Moxy Jaxb` related approach for achieving the wrapper element to the whole class?

Comment: I was able to find a temporary workaround for this issue. I am posting the same here. If incase I am able to find something different then I will update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporary workaround that works as expected for me. Posting the answer here so it can be helpful to someone in the future.

1. Change the `@XmlRootElement("customer")` to `@XmlRootElement("classWrapper")`. So you will get the `classWrapper` as the outer element.
2. Then change all the element within the `Customer` class using the `@XmlPath` so that all element go under the `Customer` tag. So overall `customer.class` would look something like this:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "classWrapper")
    @XmlType(name="customer",propOrder={"name","languages"})
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Customer{
    
      @XmlPath("customer/extension/name/text()")
      private String name;
    
      @XmlPath("customer/languages/language/text()")
      private List<String> languages;
    
      //Getter, Setter and other constuctors
    }
```

Just a tip while using the `@XmlPath`:
do not use `text()` if its not simple type such as String,Date, etc type.

For example if the element is of `Custom` type with `List` then do not use `/text()`

```
@XmlPath("extension/elements/element")
List<myType> elements;
```

This will add `extension -> elements -> element` then content.

```
<extension>
<elements>
<element></element>
<element></element>
......
</elements>
</extension>
```

If the elements are of `String` type then you have to use `text()`

```
@XmlPath("extension/elements/text()")
List<String> elements;
```